# Misplaced alignment tab character & in a BibTeX url entry

Tags: bibtex

I have a main document and I am using the natbib package to handle my bibtex database.
Here is my bottom part of the document displaying the bibliography code

```
...
\backmatter
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mybiblifile}
\end{document}
```

This is the bottom part of my code and it seems pretty normal. 
When I typeset everything after several runs of BibTeX, I get this error message:

> Misplaced alignment tab character &. You have placed an alignment tab character '&' in the wrong place. If you want to align something, you must write it inside an align environment such as \begin{align} … \end{align}, \begin{tabular} … \end{tabular}, etc. If you want to write an ampersand '&' in text, you must write \& instead.

Now I am opening the bibliography file `mybiblifile.bib`, one entry draws my attention.

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{frenkel_fine_2013,
title = {Fine temperature measurement and fabrication of on-chip whispering-gallery mode micro-sensors},
url = {http://proxy.library.nyu.edu/login?url=http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&db=edselc&AN=edselc.2-52.0-84901804547\&site=eds-live},
doi = {10.1115/MNHMT2013-22003},
booktitle = {{ASME} 2013 4th {International} {Conference} on {Micro}/{Nanoscale} {Heat} and {Mass} {Transfer}, {MNHMT} 2013},
publisher = {American Society of Mechanical Engineers (ASME)},
author = {Frenkel, M. and Avellan, M. and Guo, Z.},
year = {2013},
note = {Conference Proceedings}
}
```

I realized that it is the `&` characters inside the URL entry of the Bibtex that causes the problem. When I delete these characters from the URL entry, the typesetting works fine and no more error messages appear.

How do we deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show us a complete MWE, showing your used documentclass and used packages. Please next time show a complete MWE, not only code snippets ...

It seems you miised to call package `hyperref` (this packages calls `url` internaly) or if you do not use `hyperref` you should call package `url` or `xurl`.

See the following MWE (package `filecontents` is only used to have bib file and tex code together in a MWE):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@INPROCEEDINGS{frenkel_fine_2013,
  title = {Fine temperature measurement and fabrication of on-chip whispering-gallery mode micro-sensors},
  url = {http://proxy.library.nyu.edu/login?url=http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&db=edselc&AN=edselc.2-52.0-84901804547\&site=eds-live},
  doi = {10.1115/MNHMT2013-22003},
  booktitle = {{ASME} 2013 4th {International} {Conference} on {Micro}/{Nanoscale} {Heat} and {Mass} {Transfer}, {MNHMT} 2013},
  publisher = {American Society of Mechanical Engineers (ASME)},
  author = {Frenkel, M. and Avellan, M. and Guo, Z.},
  year = {2013},
  note = {Conference Proceedings}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

and its result without error messages:

[image]

If you do not like the empty space at the end of one line you can uncommment line

```
\usepackage{xurl}
```

in my given MWE.

Comment: I was actually thinking of posting a full MWE but it's so damn long!

Comment: Well, that is art of creating an MWE to find out which packages you used you can leave out for the MWE. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the advice and for your response! It really solved my issue and I will post an MWE from now on.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very concise and helpful answer [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=14645).

In short, insert the following line in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
```

Comment: Thank you for digging that information.  I will check it out